# Spring rabbit retries to deliver rejected message..is it OK?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have the following configuration

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.prefetch=1
spring.rabbitmq.listener.concurrency=1
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.max-attempts=3
spring.rabbitmq.listener.retry.max-interval=1000
spring.rabbitmq.listener.default-requeue-rejected=false //I have also changed it to true but the same behavior still happens
```

and in my listener I throw the exception **AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException** **to reject the message and enforce rabbit not to try to redeliver it**...But rabbit redilvers it for 3 times then finally route it to dead letter queue.

Is that the standard behavior according to my provided configuration or do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure the retry policy to not retry for that exception.

You can't do that with properties, you have to configure the retry advice yourself.

I'll post an example later if you need help with that.

`requeue-rejected` is at the container level (below retry on the stack).

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So39853762Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So39853762Application.class, args);
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        context.close();
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void foo(String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        if ("foo".equals(foo)) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("foo"); // won't be retried.
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("bar"); // will be retried
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ListenerRetryAdviceCustomizer retryCustomizer(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory,
            RabbitProperties rabbitPropeties) {
        return new ListenerRetryAdviceCustomizer(containerFactory, rabbitPropeties);
    }

    public static class ListenerRetryAdviceCustomizer implements InitializingBean {

        private final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory;

        private final RabbitProperties rabbitPropeties;

        public ListenerRetryAdviceCustomizer(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory,
                RabbitProperties rabbitPropeties) {
            this.containerFactory = containerFactory;
            this.rabbitPropeties = rabbitPropeties;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            ListenerRetry retryConfig = this.rabbitPropeties.getListener().getRetry();
            if (retryConfig.isEnabled()) {
                RetryInterceptorBuilder<?> builder = (retryConfig.isStateless()
                        ? RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                        : RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful());
                Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions = new HashMap<>();
                retryableExceptions.put(AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.class, false);
                retryableExceptions.put(IllegalStateException.class, true);
                SimpleRetryPolicy policy =
                        new SimpleRetryPolicy(retryConfig.getMaxAttempts(), retryableExceptions, true);
                ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOff = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
                backOff.setInitialInterval(retryConfig.getInitialInterval());
                backOff.setMultiplier(retryConfig.getMultiplier());
                backOff.setMaxInterval(retryConfig.getMaxInterval());
                builder.retryPolicy(policy)
                    .backOffPolicy(backOff)
                    .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer());
                this.containerFactory.setAdviceChain(builder.build());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**NOTE:** You cannot currently configure the policy to retry all exceptions, "except" this one - you have to classify all exceptions you want retried (and they can't be a superclass of `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`). I have opened an [issue to support this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/56).

Comment: Thanks for the post @GaryRussell - I could not figure out why AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException I was throwing inside of my consumer containers were being retried.  Now I get it - RetryPolicy governs this.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers posted here didn't work me when using Spring Boot 2.3.5 and Spring AMQP Starter 2.2.12, but for these versions I was able to customize the retry policy to not retry AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException exceptions:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

@Bean
public RabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer customizeRetryPolicy(
        @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts}") int maxAttempts) {
    SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts, Map.of(AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.class, false), true, true);
    return (target, retryTemplate) -> retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(policy);
}
```

}

This lets the retry policy skip retries for AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueExceptions but retries all other exceptions as usual.

Configured this way, it traverses the causes of an exception, and skips retries if it finds an AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.

Traversing the causes is needed as `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter#invokeHandler` wraps all exceptions as a `ListenerExecutionFailedException`