# Rabbit mQ messages moving from ready queue to Unack queue

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, spring-rabbit

I have a separate publisher and consumer.I start publisher and publish messages.Now i start consumer and problem is that the messages move from ready queue to unack queue marking the messages as redelivered which i want to avoid.So what i want is it should be marked as redelivered only if i send ack and not on consumer restart or start

Configuration :

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.Connection mqConnection() {
    CloudFactory cloudFactory = new CloudFactory();
    Cloud cloud = cloudFactory.getCloud();
    return cloud.getServiceConnector("mqservicename", ConnectionFactory.class,
            null).createConnection();
} 
@Bean
public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful().retryOperations(retryTemplate()).recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())

            .build();
}
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter());
    container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] {
           interceptor()
    });

    return container;
}



@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(){
    Map map=new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>();
    map.put(CustomException.class, true);
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate=new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(3,map));
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are ACKing the messages?

Comment: Yes ,i was.Now with Garys comment i kept it off and tried with above configuration.But it gives only 1 try and not 3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring AMQP, you need to show your configuration when asking questions like this.

If you set the ack mode to MANUAL, you are responsible for the acks. Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/). For AUTO ackmode, the container will ack the message when the listener returns normally.

Comment: I could resolve that by changing the logic of redelivery sued in code.But the problem now is with small volume of data I could properly test,but with large volume of data,i am getting below exception :

Comment: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 123, class-id=60, method-id=80)

Comment: To add the details,I give 3 chances to a message based on redeliver flag.For every failure(some logic which does some validation of message ) ,i use basicNack and requeue to true.On last failure,i use basicknack and requeue to false.For success,i use basicAck and requeue to false.

Comment: The delivery tag is relative to the channel. Rather than trying to roll your own solution, you can use a stateful retry interceptor ([described here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#retry)) with AUTO ack mode, configure it with a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` and it will do exactly what you need.

Comment: I have added configuration.SimpleMessageListenerContainer forces to set connectionfactory.I tried by using AbstractCloudConfig's method but it did not allow.Without using SimpleMessageListenerContainer,it does only single retry.What I found is retry is done based on some rules set by rabbitmq,But I want retry whenever some validation logic in my code for the message fails i.e retry on custom condition.So with above how would rabbitmq know that it has to retry for the message as i have set autoack to true in channel.basicConsume()?Please note i am using cloud foundry service for rabbitmq.

Comment: You need to customize the retry policy to tell it which exceptions should be retried and which should not. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853762/spring-rabbit-retries-to-deliver-rejected-message-is-it-ok/39854190#39854190) for an example.