# Spring AMQP how to access response message when connection is lost while sending using @SendTo

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

we have a microservice which consumes a message using @RabbitListener and persist data into database, generate a response on successful processing of message and send it using @sendTO to different queue for auditing.

When running Rabbit in HA failover, while sending response if connection is lost the message currently being processed is correctly returned to the queue but database transaction (jpa transaction in our case) is not rolled back , response is never sent.

I read from this issue(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/696)  that this is "best effort 1PC" transaction synchronization; RabbitMQ does not support XA transactions. The Rabbit tx is committed after the DB tx and there is a possibility the DB tx might commit and the rabbit rolled back; you have to deal with the small possibility of duplicate messages.

But in our case when we retry request, we are treating it as duplicate message and response is never created for this request. is there a way where we can only retry sending response message in case of connection lost exceptions rather than reprocessing request again? I looked at ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy, it has access only to original request,no way to access response lost during connection failure. Please suggest what's the best way to handle this?

our code looks like:

```
SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.***")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class PcaClinicalValidationApplication {

@RabbitListener(queues = "myqueue"
  @SendTo("exchange/routingKey")
  @Timed) description = "Time taken to process a request")
  public Message receivemessage(HashMap<String, Object> myMap, Message requestMessage)
      throws Exception {
   //business logic goes here
Message message = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(requestMessage)
//add some headers
return message;

}

public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(new RetryTemplate());
        factory.setReplyRecoveryCallback(ctx -> {
            Message failed = SendRetryContextAccessor.getMessage(ctx);          
            Address replyTo = SendRetryContextAccessor.getAddress(ctx);
            Throwable t = ctx.getLastThrowable();

     //wrote to a file          
     serializer.serialize(failed);
            return null;
        });
        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The listener container factory uses a `RabbitTemplate` in its `replyTemplate` property - this is used to send the reply.

You can configure a `RetryTemplate` into that `RabbitTemplate` to retry sending the reply.

When retries are exhausted, you can add a `RecoveryCallback` which will get the failed reply and you can save it off someplace and use it when the redelivery occurs.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your help. I will try it out.

Comment: Hi Gary, I tried factory.setRetryTemplate(new RetryTemplate()) and factory.setReplyRecoveryCallback to recover my response and was able to serialize to a file. Thank you.
since I'm able to recover my response, I don't want my requestMessage to be requed. what is the correct way for this setting on listener Container setting DefaultRequeueRejected to false or should I configure any retryInterceptor with RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer(). I read so many different solutions, kinda got confused. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853762/spring-rabbit-retries-to-deliver-rejected-message-is-it-ok

Comment: I don't see replyTemplate property on SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory, unless I misunderstood you. could you please post an example for me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake; we don't use a `RabbitTemplate` for replies (I was thinking of the Kafka equivalent where we have a `replyTemplate`). So what you have is correct; as long as your recovery callback "recovers" the message (doesn't throw an exception), the message will not be requeued.

Comment: ah no problem. I have updated my question with factory configuration. Even though I;m writing my response to a file , my original request message is getting requeued. recovery callback is not throwing any exceptions.Am I doing something wrong?
I send a request, message gets processed and persists into database, I killed rabbitmq just before response being sent. After exhausting retries response message is written to a file but my request is requeued and getting processed again once I start my rabbitmq.

Comment: Well, of course it's requeued :) - the response is sent on the same channel the request was received on; if the channel is closed (preventing the send) then we also can't send the acknowledgment for the request, so it will be requeued. You might say - "well what if I use manual acks and perform the ack after the DB commit but before the send". All that will do is shrink the timing window, but the probability of duplicates is still non-zero. You really need to handle duplicate deliveries.

Comment: I see your point. We have updated our code to handle duplicate deliveries. it's working well now..Thank you, for all the suggestions..one last question..will there be any chance while using @SendTo..rabbitmq goes down after request is acked just before sending response..or acking request and sending response happen at the same time?

Comment: The ack is performed when the listener thread returns to the container (after the message is sent).